# PHP sort numbers all zero without changing index

Tags: php, arrays

The `asort(arrivalTime[])` is not correct. How to correct this when I put all zero on all? The display is:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [0] => 0
)
```

it should be like this and not affecting the index... cause no need to sort when all zero...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

and when I input another with there is not zero this will the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
)
```

can anyone have another solution?

**EDIT**
when I used ksort() this is the result... when I input 0, 2, 1
and this is the simple code

```
<?php
    $test = array(0,2,1);
    ksort($test);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($test);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

the output is bug

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)
```

---

all I want is when I put 0,0,0,1 and not changing the key because it's the same...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
)
```

then another input is 0,2,1,3

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: after 5 questions you should know how to format code

Comment: what action do you like perform with this array? will use foreach loop with this array? or anything else?

Comment: @samiul i use for loop only...

Comment: @kennypu my code is just firstComeFirstServe calculator so need to sort the arrival time and when the arrival have all 0 they misplaced... so now I fixed it already thanks to all anyway...

Comment: @JeraldPunx11 then remove index from array, use sort and do foreach loop, so you can get sorted array and index can be get from foreach key.

Comment: @kennypu hey i show code on edit... please help still have bugs...

Answer (score 1):

use `ksort()` function to sort your arrays by their keys.

Answer (score 0):

To your question use the `ksort()`, as the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

> ksort(arrivalTime[]);

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations.

```
$test = array(0,2,1,3);
arsort($test);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";

$test = array(0,0,0,1);
ksort($test);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";

if($test == array(0,0,0,1)){
    ksort($test);
} else{
    asort($test);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: but what if i input `4 5 9 2 3` does it sort into `2 3 4 5 9` ?

Comment: @JeraldPunx11 Yes. Will ordernar by key, maintaining the correlation between keys and values

Comment: @Loïc, excuse me. When I sent the response that came to your answer.

Comment: @JeraldPunx11 But Array([0] => 0,[1] => 2,[2] => 1,[3] => 3) is equal to Array([0] => 0,[2] => 1,[1] => 2,[3] => 3). The first is ordered by key but not the latter, but the correlation key and value is the same.

Comment: @LucasHenrique but how to do that sort?

Comment: @JeraldPunx11 sort the key or value? Maintains correlation key and value?

Comment: @LucasHenrique look on the EDIT area where on line `all I want is when` and that's what I want to do...

Comment: @JeraldPunx11 if 0,0,0,1 is ksort(), if 0,2,1,3 is asort(). Would that be?

Comment: @LucasHenrique can I use them both? cause when I input `0,0,0,1` the keys is displaced it should displaced the key since they are all zero